# Dockerfile unable to copy testng.xml file to docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pom.xml, testng.xml

I have springrestapi project setup in my local with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file successfully running. Now I have added my api tests as part of this project inside the same repository by adding a new directory called in-memory-tests.

in-memory-tests directory has Dockerfile in it. This Dockerfile has commands to copy to image. when i run docker-compose.yml file. its giving below error.

### [+] Running 0/1
⠿ testserv1 Error                                                                                                                                                     5.1s
[+] Building 3.1s (8/10)
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                   0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                      0.0s
=> => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine                                                                                            3.0s
=> CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine@sha256:c1439df43e994b9df98063458e704384b85914c8bef4c1de22f992f51dcc2d79                               0.0s
=> [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                      0.0s
=> => transferring context: 879B                                                                                                                                      0.0s
=> CACHED [2/6] COPY src /app/src                                                                                                                                     0.0s
=> ERROR [3/6] COPY testng.xml /app/                                                                                                                                  0.0s
=> ERROR [4/6] COPY reports/testreport.html /app/reports/                                                                                                             0.0s

> [3/6] COPY testng.xml /app/:

---

---

> [4/6] COPY reports/testreport.html /app/reports/:

---

failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/reports/testreport.html" not found: not found

[image]
[Github repo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0sW5.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0sW5.png): [[image]]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0sW5.png)https://github.com/aamirsuhailo1/SpringRestAPIsOnDocker/tree/testframework_addition

[image]

Comment: What are the image files you've included in the question?  Can you [edit] the question to include enough details to reproduce the question; especially the Dockerfile and `docker-compose.yml` files (as code-formatted text, not images)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got resolved after adding
context: ./in-memory-tests/ and removing  dockerfile: in-memory-tests/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a build context in `docker-compose.yml > testserv1 > build`.  If you provide a dockerfile property you must also set the [context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#dockerfile).

Alternatively you can just set the [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#build-definition) property, to the **directory** that contains a `Dockerfile`, in your case `build: .` should suffice, as the `docker-compose.yml` is in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: docker- compose.yml is not in same directory as testserv1. It's outside of that directory

Comment: From the screenshot it seems that it's in. If it's not then `build: ./in-memory-tests` should get you what you need.